# how do i make a notch filter for this image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

so i have this image [orignal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c5Uk.jpg)
and its Fourier spectrum is [Fourier Spectrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux5IS.png)
i want to denoise the image but i have no idea how to get a filter to remove all these bright peeks.
any working code or formula would be appreciated.

right now i have this code which gives me the noise only

```
im = imread("im.tif");
im = im2double(im);
fftim = fft2(im);
power_spectrum = abs(fftim).^2;
power_spectrum = fftshift(power_spectrum);
%ffim = log(1 + ffim);
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(im,[]);
title('orignal image');
subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(power_spectrum, []);
title('Fourier Transform');
%---------------------------------
threshold = 0.1 * max(max(power_spectrum));
peakMask = power_spectrum > threshold;
se = strel('disk', 5); 
peakMask = imdilate(peakMask, se);
peakMask = imerode(peakMask, se);
[peakRows, peakCols] = find(peakMask);
mask = ones(size(power_spectrum));  % Initialize the mask
roi_size = 20;  
for i = 1:numel(peakRows)
row = peakRows(i);
col = peakCols(i);
mask(row-roi_size:row+roi_size, col-roi_size:col+roi_size) = 0; 
end
filterdspectrum = power_spectrum.* mask;
filterdspectrum = ifftshift(filterdspectrum);
filterdspectrum = ifft2(filterdspectrum);
filterdspectrum = uint8(real(filterdspectrum));
imshow(filterdspectrum);
```

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki no need to get the offensive i only asked for the formula to detect the peeks, i also added the code if you want to look at it

Comment: Sorry for the rough introduction. We have nicer copy-paste templates that mods paste as comments for new users who are missing question requirements. @SembeiNorimaki I know it's annoying to go through questions that don't follow the site rules, but for new contributors it's best to just paste the template and move on. For future reference you can find the templates here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments